# Can't iterate through words in a file and append string to each line

Tags: python, io

I am reading in a list of words from a file. I want to append a string to each word, then print out the word with the appended string. 
However, my current code appends the string on a new line.

```
with open("wordDict.txt") as wordFile:
    for line in wordFile:
        line = line + 'a'
        print(line)
```

An example output I get is this:

```
hello
a
```

Output I want to get:

```
helloa
```

Any help appreciated

Comment: you need to strip the spaces and linebreaks of each lines, with `line.strip()` for example

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
with open("wordDict.txt") as wordFile:
    for line in wordFile:
        line = line.strip() + 'a'
        print(line)
```

You need to get rid of the line break at the end of the line. `.strip()` gets rid of whitespace at either end of the line.

Answer (score 2):

```
with open("wordDict.txt") as wordFile:
    for line in wordFile:
        line = line.rstrip() + 'a'
        print(line)
```

should do the trick. [rstrip](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.rstrip) removes trailing whitespace, including newlines.